# Argument passed in must be a string of 24 hex characters - I think it is

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I have a method to find a document in my database based on its ObjectID:

```
      console.log('id: ' + id + ' type: ' + typeof id);
      collection.findOne({'_id':new ObjectID(id)}, function(error,doc) {
        if (error) {
          callback(error);
        } else {
           callback(null, doc);
        }
      });
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
/myPath/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:245
    throw message;      
          ^
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at new ObjectID (/myPath/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:38:11)
at /myPath/collectionDriver.js:134:41
```

This refers to the `collection.findOne()` line above.

The console log I have before that call outputs the id as a string of 24 hex characters:

```
id: "55153a8014829a865bbf700d" type: string
```

Before this I convert the id from an object to a string using `JSON.stringify()` but it appears to work successfully as shown in my console.log.

Running `db.myCollection.findOne({_id : ObjectId("55153a8014829a865bbf700d")})` in Robomongo brings back the expected result.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The id that was passed in to my function was already an object ID in this case, so did not need a new ObjectID to be created from it.

When ObjectIDs are logged out to the console they appear as hex strings, rather than `ObjectID("hexString")`, so I thought I needed to convert it to do the find, but it was already in the format that I needed.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm running into this issue as well, however, if I remove ObjectId(...) I get an Invalid Arg Type Error. If I leave the object Id, it works, but I get this error message every time. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var hex = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
id = (hex.test(id))? ObjectId(id) : id;
collection.findOne({'_id':new ObjectID(id)}, function(error,doc) {
  if (error) {
    callback(error);
  } else {
    callback(null, doc);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this worked:

```
var myId = JSON.parse(req.body.id);
    collection.findOne({'_id': ObjectID(myId)}, function(error,doc) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
       callback(null, doc);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to include at the beginning:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I just spent thirty minutes baffled by this. If anyone finds themselves here, first check if you even need to convert to ObjectID in the first place. Like OP, I forgot that the hexstring is logged as just that - a hexstring.

Answer (score 1):

Try out `ObjectID(id)` instead of `new ObjectID(id)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not change the outcome.

Comment: I just tried following code nad it recognizing hexstring:

`var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;ObjectID.createFromHexString('55153a8014829a865bbf700d')
55153a8014829a865bbf700d`

Comment: Yeah, works for me like that too, but not with my input, which apparently isn't the hex string it appears to be.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Later I found that I have included a whitespace while sending the values to the server.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id %>" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
```

In the value attribute I had typed as `value="<%= item._id %> "` . A whitespace after the ID. It caused to that error. After I removed it(`value="<%= item._id %>"` ), the problem solved.

The below code worked for me.

```
item.findOne({'_id':id} , (err)=>{

if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
else{
  console.log("Item Found");
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Id you are fetching have whitespaces in it so adding trim() to your id will work

```
const id = (req.params.id).trim();
const result =  await deleteOne({_id:new mongodb.ObjectId(id)});
```

while using this code keep in mind that your function should be async and mongodb should have been imported.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but trimming the productId passed to ObjectId() worked for me

Earlier:

```
    const objectId = new ObjectID(productId);
    product = await db?.collection('products').find({ _id: objectId }).next();
```

Now:

```
    const objectId = new ObjectID(productId.trim());                                       
    product = await db?.collection('products').find({ _id: objectId }).next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of this,

make sure the value must not have any whitespace,

you can use
`const ID =  id.trim(); then use ObjectId(ID)`

Thanks
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Argument passed in must be a string of 24 hex characters
if you are getting this error then.
just do this

use .trim() to delete any extra character usually a space is added to the id. and it becomes 25 hex charater .
so instead of _id = yourId;
use  _id = yourId.trim()

Answer (score 0):

`collection.find({ _id: { $in: req.body.map(pd => ObjectId(pd)) } })`

use `map()` on the `res.body` --  it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ID = (req.body.id).trim();
```

Worked for me, actually `(req.body.id)` adds an extra space to the ID variable.

After I used `.trim()` method it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all answers. But it doesn't work for me. Maybe if you are getting params with express. It's worked for me. Try this;

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

var reqId = req.params.id
var query = reqId.toString()


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("AllDB");
    dbo.collection("Events").findOne({_id: ObjectId(query)}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result)
        db.close();
      });
});

})
```

**Update :**

Hey, I give same error again, and I notice new solution. If your code like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('TEST')
})


app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

   var reqId = req.params.id
   var query = reqId.toString()

})
```

Could you try change your get request route. Maybe such as app.get('/findid/:id)

It worked for me. I was searching again and i found this way.

Thanks, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes clearing your local storage could be the solution to this error. From 'inspect' just go to  Application>local storage and select the URL. Then press the 'clear all' sign. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I have used this   const product = await Product.findOne({'_id':id}), it solved the error

```js
const {_id, name, description}=product||{}




export const read = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //const product = await Product.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
    const product = await Product.findOne({'_id':id})
    
      .select("-photo")
      .populate("category");

    res.json(product);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**USE trim()**
I also have this error: In my case, it is due to the white space after the object ID that I passed. By using the trim() function

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when i was facing issue, The User table has relations with Types table with reference of ID, I was passing string, instead of a ObjectId which is  24 hex character, so you mush check it once.