# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Users", in findOne and others

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am fairly new to mongodb and nodejs. I am getting an error by when I try to get specific user
by req.params.id from database.

```
app.get('/user/:id', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    Users.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err,user) => { 
        if(!err) {                                      
            res.send(user)                           
            console.log(user);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('Error Happened')
        }
    })
})
```

in mongodb atlas I am getting
{
_id : (hexstring)
name :
email:
address:
__v:
}

.
Every line or block of code containing req.params.id is giving errors, while Users.save() is working and .remove() is also working fine and I think .find() is also working fine

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051236/argument-passed-in-must-be-a-string-of-24-hex-characters-i-think-it-is

Comment: @about14sheep , it does but how do I import objectId in es6 ? and when I am importing it is giving me error like this.splitpath() is not a function, when I put    { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)  }

Comment: `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;` would be how to import it. try removing the new keywords

Comment: @about14sheep not working in .mjs extension. should I convert it to .js ?

Comment: Sorry i thought you were using commonjs. for .mjs the import statement would be `import {ObjectID} from 'mongodb'`

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, `ObjectId` has a [strict requirement](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) of being a 12-byte string.

`"1"` is not a valid ObjectId.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get it through params ?

Comment: I updated the code and wrote whole code I am working on, It's a basic crud application