# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

I am stuck at this error everyday.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model

reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

I already Google all possible solution but none of them can fix the error. The code for back-end is:

```
router.get('/findUser/:_id', async(req,res)=>{

  console.log(req.params._id);
  const user = await LaundryUser.findById(req.params._id);

  if(!user) {
      res.status(500).json({message: 'The user with the given ID was not found.'})
  } 
  res.status(200).send(user);
})
```

And for the front-end is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (
      context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === false ||
      context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === null
    ) {
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    }

    AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt")
      .then((res) => {
        axios
          .get(`${baseURL}users/findUser/${context.stateUser.laundryuser.sub}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res}` },
          })
          .then((laundryuser) => setUserProfile(laundryuser.data));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    return () => {
      setUserProfile();
    };
  }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated]);
```

Why this error happened? I use Postman to try the back-end code, and the code is functioning well because it can find the user based on id. However, when I used the front-end code, the error occur. Why when I use the Postman, it functioning well but when use front-end code, error occur? Is there any problem with my front-end code?

Also, when I try to console log the id, it display undefined. Can someone help me. Stuck about a week and no solution.

Comment: Try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051236/argument-passed-in-must-be-a-string-of-24-hex-characters-i-think-it-is

Comment: I tried but still not solve

Comment: "${context.stateUser.laundryuser.sub}"
did you check in console what is the value given here?

Comment: It means that the frontend code does not send your _id properly, but sends "undefined" instead.